# How do I change the image from the default mysteryman in the WP Profile page

Tags: plugin-development, images, profiles

I work for a company that has recently added a plugin for WordPress. We have a company profile page, as the plugin owner, and we want to change the image from the the default mysteryman to a logo. I realize this is a small detail to most of you, but I am a tech. writer not a developer and am in need of some help.

Thank you in advance.
Yaacovg

Comment: After I wrote the answer... Do you actually mean change it somewhere on _your_ WP site or on wordpress  org ?

Answer (score 1):

Sadly natively WP doesn't allow to set custom default avatar in settings, just choose from fixed selection of options.

Avatar retrieval is handled by [`get_avatar()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_avatar/) function, which accepts third `$default` argument to which you can pass URL to desired default image. You will need to edit your theme to accomplish it in that way, or (going even deeper) to make use of its internal filters.

I would first do some searching for existing plugin to accomplish this, it seems like typical need so there is bound to be one.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `http://wordpress.org/support/profile/YOUR_USERNAME/edit` and set an email address that has an account on [gravatar.com](http://gravatar.com/). On Gravatar.com, you can change the image.

> [image]

Note that no other profile address will offer an email field. `http://profiles.wordpress.org/YOUR_USERNAME/profile/` for example doesn’t, and there is no link to the other page.

Comment: I cannot get to "http://wordpress.org/support/profile/YOUR_USERNAME/edit" it automatically take me to "http://wordpress.org/support/profile/YOUR_USERNAME/edit/group/1/"

Answer (score 0):

You could do update_option function to replace the default avatar with your avatar url.

It would go something like this (just put it in your functions.php and after it works out, delete it).

```
update_option( 'avatar_default', 'http://mydomain.com/avatar.png' );
```